# Image factorization in a category

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$ is a cover in a category (i.e. a morphism which does not factor through any proper subobject) and let $g\colon B\longrightarrow C$ a morphism with image $D\rightarrowtail C$. I have been asked to prove or disprove that then the image of $g\circ f$ coincides with the image of $g$. I think this should be true but I am not able to prove it.

Comment: Which notion of image is meant here?

Comment: By image of $g\colon B\rightarrow C$ I mean a subobject $m\colon D\rightarrowtail C$ (more precisely a class of isomorphism of monomorphisms with codomain $C$) satisfying that $g$ factors through $m$ and if $g$ factors through any other mono $n$ then there is a morphism $k$ such that $ k m= n$ (i.e. $m$ is the smallest one wrt to the partial order of subobjects).

Comment: Don't you mean $nk=m$ in your comment above?

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry!

Comment: The definition of a cover is new to me. Would you give me a reference—preferably a textbook—using it?

Comment: @Orat It's more commonly called an extremal epimorphism, and sometimes a surjection.

Comment: If a counterexample exists then $f$ must not be split epimorphism, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the category with two objects $I$ and $T,$ with all hom-sets singletons except for $T$ which has three self-maps $1_T,f,f^2$ obeying $f^2=f^3.$ The composite $T\to I\to T$ is $f^2:T\to T.$ (If it helps: this category is the [Karoubi envelope](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubi+envelope) of the monoid $T=\langle f\mid f^2=f^3\rangle.$) Take $f=g.$ They're both extremal epi, but the composite $f^2$ factors through $I\rightarrowtail T.$